# Why is my ASP.NET web service unable to complete this POST request?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xamarin, json.net, restsharp

I have a data-entry app built in Xamarin.Forms that's designed to capture data into a particular format, then post that via an ASP.NET web service into a SQL Server. I'm using `RestSharp` to make this easier. Below is the code I currently have to do this:

```
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string userResponse = await DisplayActionSheet("Are you sure?", "Yes", "No");
                if (userResponse == "Yes")
                {   
                    using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(App.DatabaseLocation))
                    {
                        List<DataToBeSent> d = conn.Query<DataToBeSent>("select * from DataToBeSent");
                        var dConvert = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(d, Formatting.Indented);
                        var client = new RestClient("url here");
                        client.Timeout = -1;
                        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
                        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
                        Token token = conn.Query<Token>("select * from Token").FirstOrDefault();
                        request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token.access_token);
                        request.AddParameter("application/json", dConvert, ParameterType.RequestBody);
                        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
                        await DisplayAlert("", response.StatusCode.ToString() + response.Content.ToString(), "OK");
                    }
                    await Navigation.PopToRootAsync();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Error", $"Data failed to be inserted.\n{ex}", "OK");
            }
            
        }
```

And it returns the following alert when I try to submit any data:
[image]

The `Token` class uses a successful `POST` request to retrieve an OAuth token for the app to use to `GET` data when it starts up.

I've also tested with Postman, sample request below:
[image]
[image]

Which causes the following error in my web service:
[image]

<s>It is worth noting that the table to which I am posting data **does not have a primary key.** It's unfortunate but it's a requirement that it does not have one.</s> **Table now has a primary key (named `UniqueID`)**. I also noticed that the `List<DataToBeSent>`, when serialized, returns with escape characters. Why are these errors occurring? Does anyone know how to fix them?

**Update 1:** As requested;
JSON being passed as below.

```
"[\n  {\n    \"column1\": \"data1\",\n    \"column2\": \"data2\"\n  }\n]"
```

Code for database model as below.

```
<!--Errors Found During Generation:
warning 6002: The table/view 'databaseName.dbo.DataToBeSent' does not have a primary key defined. The key has been inferred and the definition was created as a read-only table/view.-->
        <EntityType Name="DataToBeSent">
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="column1" />
            <PropertyRef Name="column2" />
          </Key>
          <Property Name="column1" Type="nvarchar" MaxLength="50" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="column2" Type="nvarchar" MaxLength="50" Nullable="false" />
        </EntityType>
<EntitySet Name="DataToBeSent" EntityType="Self.DataToBeSent" store:Type="Tables" store:Schema="dbo">
            <DefiningQuery>
              SELECT
              [DataToBeSent].[column1] AS [column1],
              [DataToBeSent].[column2] AS [column2]
            </DefiningQuery>
          </EntitySet>
```

**Update 2:** I have tried updating my `POST` request code in the Xamarin backend. This is what I have currently.

```
List<DataToBeSent> DATA = conn.Query<DataToBeSent>("select * from DataToBeSent");
                        var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DATA, Formatting.None);
                        Token token = conn.Query<Token>("select * from Token").FirstOrDefault();
                        var client = new RestClient("url");
                        client.Timeout = -1;
                        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
                        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                        request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token.access_token);
                        request.AddJsonBody(data);
                        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
                        await DisplayAlert("Response", response.StatusCode + response.Content, "OK");
```

I don't know why the Serialization error occurs - when viewing the results in Visual Studio as a `JSON` object the escape characters are absent. This would indicate to me that the serialization is occuring correctly, yet I still get the same error message (BadRequest). I am trying to submit a `List<>` of objects so I'm wondering if `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` is the right method to be using.

**Update 3:** I have tried POSTing a single object as suggested by @Mat J below. Code is the same as Update 2 except for changing the `List<>` object to a single object with `.FirstOrDefault()`. See below.

```
DataToBeSent DATA = conn.Query<DataToBeSent>("select * from DataToBeSent").FirstOrDefault();
var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DATA, Formatting.None);
```

Response as displayed in app.
[image]

Below is my controller's code from the web service. I generated it automatically as a `Web API 2 Controller, using Entity Framework`, and added the square brackets above it to use my OAuth security methods.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin, User")]
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/v/DataToBeSent")]
[ResponseType(typeof(DataToBeSent))]
public IHttpActionResult PostDataToBeSent(DataToBeSent dataToBeSent)
 {
      if (!ModelState.IsValid)
      {
          return BadRequest(ModelState);
      }

      db.DataToBeSent.Add(dataToBeSent);

      try
      {
          db.SaveChanges();
      }
      catch (DbUpdateException)
      {
          if (DataToBeSentExists(dataToBeSent.UniqueID))
          {
              return Conflict();
          }
          else
          {
              throw;
          }
      }

      return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = dataToBeSent.UniqueID }, dataToBeSent);
  }
```

The `DataToBeSent` table **now has a Primary Key, named `UniqueID` as above.**

I do want to be able to submit a whole `List<>` of objects rather than doing something like a for-loop and making a separate `POST` call for each individual object in the list.

Comment: the first error message is pretty clear - it expects an object and you are passing an array.  It even offers a suggestion of how to fix it.  But you haven't shown us 1) the code for the model, 2) the json being passed, and 3) the signature of the webservice, so it's impossible to tell you what you might need to change

Comment: the 2nd error appears to be an EF issue.  Googling the error message returns hundreds of hits, several of which are from prior questions on SO

Comment: Added 1) and 2), how can I find the signature of the webservice?
@Jason yes, I have tried several solutions such as deleting the DefiningQuery and updated store:Schema to just Schema, neither of which worked for me.

Comment: If it is not clear to you yet, the error is generated in web service. You are sending an array, web service has a signature similar to `public ActionResult ApiEndpoint(DataToBeSent model)` while you are calling it like `ApiEndpoint(listOfDataToBeSent)` which is causing error. Send one object by adding a `FirsOrDefault` call at the end of your query.

Comment: Please see results of testing with `FirstOrDefault` in recent edits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out the issue, posting it here for anyone experiencing problems in the future. As @Mat J pointed out in the question's comments, I was trying to send an array when the controller was only set up to receive single objects. Step 1 was updating that code to allow the controller to receive a `List<>` instead of a single object. Step 2 was realizing that I'd set the `POST` controller's `[Route]` attribute to be identical to the table's `GET` controller. The working Xamarin-side code can found in the question's **Update 2**, although @Alexey Zimarev's answer would probably be more efficient. Updated web service controller code can be found below.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin, User")]
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/postall/datatobesent")]
public IHttpActionResult PostAllDataToBeSent([FromBody] List<DataToBeSent> dataToBeSent)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    foreach(var data in dataToBeSent)
    {
        db.DataToBeSent.Add(data);
    }

    try
    {
        db.SaveChanges();

        return Ok();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }

}
```

Thank you to all who commented and contributed.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest reading RestSharp docs. We tried to make it easier to use, I am not sure why you are not taking benefit of it.

Let's look at this code:

```
var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DATA, Formatting.None);
Token token = conn.Query<Token>("select * from Token").FirstOrDefault();
var client = new RestClient("url");
client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token.access_token);
request.AddJsonBody(data);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

- To start with, `AddJsonBody` accepts an `object`, which gets serialized for you. You are sending a `string`, which already contains a serialized object, so this would never work.
- By calling `AddJsonObject` you already set the content type to `application/json`, there's no need to do it again.
- Instead of using the bearer header set manually, you can just use the `JwtAuthenticator` that is built for the purpose of authentication without a need to manipulate headers for each request.
- The client is advised to be a singleton, not to be re-created for each request.

I can suggest using the following:

```
public void WhateverIsCalledOnce()
{
    var roken = conn.Query<Token>("select * from Token").First();
    _client = new RestClient("url").UseNewtonsoftJson();
    _client.Authenticator = new JwtAuthenticator(token.access_token);
}

public async Task CallRemoteServer()
{
    var data = await _connection.GetDataFromDb("query");
    var request = new RestRequest("/api/v/DataToBeSent")
        .AddJsonBody(data);
    var result = await _client.PostAsync<DataToBeReturned>(request);
}
```

The `UseNewtonsoftJson` extension method is available in the `RestSharp.Serializers.NewtonsoftJson` package on NuGet.